# MySQL WHERE clause with LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql

I get a syntax error when use a WHERE clause with the SQL query below. The query works without the where clause ad the where clause works with a simple 'SELECT * FROM' query with no joins. The original query uses PDO and bind parameters but I'm using straight SQL for this example so I can get the syntax right first. Where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT bk.*, au.author_firstname, au.author_surname, pu.publisher_name
FROM books bk
LEFT JOIN authors au ON bk.author_id = au.author_id
LEFT JOIN publishers pu ON bk.publisher_id = pu.publisher_id
ORDER BY title
WHERE bk.author_id = 13
```

Comment: `where` must come before `order by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   SELECT bk.*, au.author_firstname, au.author_surname, pu.publisher_name
     FROM books bk
LEFT JOIN authors au 
       ON bk.author_id = au.author_id
LEFT JOIN publishers pu 
       ON bk.publisher_id = pu.publisher_id
    WHERE bk.author_id = 13
 ORDER BY title
```

`Where` comes before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response. As you will have gathered I'm a MySQL  newbie. I've fixed the PDO version and am back coding. You've saved my morning. Cheers!